# Why does printf print the incorrect value?

Tags: c, printf

The following code always prints `"0.00"`. I was expecting `"7888"`. Should I convert it to `double`?

```
long l = 7888;
printf("%.2f", l);
```

Comment: If using gcc/clang you may use `-Wformat` to have warning for your wrong format.

Comment: Even if the type was correct you'd still get `7888.00`

Comment: suggest when compiling, to always enable all the compiler warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')  Then fix the warnings.

Comment: `%.2f` is not a valid format for a `long`.  Switch to a `double`, or change `f` for `d`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `%f` format specifier expects a `double`, but you're passing it a `long`, so that's undefined behavior.

If you want to print it properly, you need to either use the `%ld` format specifier to print it as a `long`:

```
printf("%ld", l);
```

Or cast `l` to `double` to print it as a floating point number:

```
printf("%.2f", (double)l);
```

Answer (score 13):

`%.2f` is not a valid format for a `long`. You can cast it to double:

```
long l = 7888;
printf("%.2f", (double)l);
```

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/#parameters) is a table (scroll a bit down) where you can see which codes are allowed for all number types.

Answer (score 8):

`%f` expects a `double` and `l` variable is a long. `printf()` does not convert it's arguments to a type required by the format specifier *all-by-itself* magically.

FWIW, `printf()` being a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), default argument promotion rule is applied on the supplied arguments, and it does not change a `long` to `double`, either. If at all, you want that conversion to happen, you have to *cast* the argument value explicitly.

You need to write something like

```
printf("%.2f", (double)l);
```

---

Please note, this code invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), without an *explicit* cast. Reference, `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, `fprintf()`

> [....] If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> I was expecting "7888".
> ```

This happens because you are trying to print LONG with FLOAT identifier.
The compiler complains about that if you turn your setting on:

> ```
> program.c:5:5: error: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Werror=format=]
>      printf("%f", l);
>      ^
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```

.

> ```
> Should I convert it to double?
> ```

By the way you can cast it too, if this is what you really need.

I think this is what you realy need:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    long l = 7888;
    printf("%ld", l);
    return 0;
}
```

> 7888

Answer (score 1):

You cannot printf a long proberly with a float identifier. What do you want do achieve?